# What are the valid content types for Controller.File()?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, file, content-type, asp.net-mvc-controller

I'm using MVC 4 in Visual Studio.  I want to know how to create a file with the Controller.File() method. I understand I need to pass a file type.  What are the valid file types?  I'm not seeing this in the documentation (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492492(v=vs.108).aspx).

Example code:

```
return File(answers, "txt",filename);
```

Is there a list of content types that someone can reference me?  I need to know format of the "txt" argument (or whatever I'm supposed to be putting there) basically (e.g. "txt" or ".txt" or "text/html" or "*.txt", etc.).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Those are [mime types](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_media_type).
There are extensive lists of them all over the internet, including the [official list](http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types) from IANA.

Comment: Ah thanks.  I'm guessing that this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms775147(v=vs.85).aspx#Known_MimeTypes) would be the list of mime types accepted by MS then?

Comment: @levininja: Not "accepted by MS", but recognized by default IE.  Other browsers and platforms will recognize other MIME types, and programs or addins can add more on any platform / browser.  The server doesn't care at all.

Comment: Ah, that makes total sense, since the file will be downloaded on the user's browser ultimately.  Thanks for the clarification.